# Refresh div that contains db data with a button

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to implements a button that can refresh the content of a div. This div contains values taken with ajax from the database.
There is a function that can do it?

This is the main page:

```
include("top.php");
include("funzioni.php");
is_logged();
?>
<script src="JavaScript/inserisciMateria.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<body>
<?= include ("navbar.html") ?>
    <div class="corpo">
        <p class="titolo"> Scegli l'anno di cui ti interessa vedere i corsi disponibili! </p>
        <hr>
        <div class="anni">  
            <<button id="ShowPrimoAnno" >Primo Anno</button>
            <button id="ShowSecondoAnno" >Secondo Anno</button>
            <button id="ShowTerzoAnno" >Terzo Anno</button>
            <button id="ShowQuartoAnno" >Quarto Anno</button>
            <button id="ShowQuintoAnno" >Quinto Anno</button>
        </div>
</div>
<script src="JavaScript/selezionaAnno.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to implement it on the button ShowPrimoAnno, in the file **selezionaAnno**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#ShowPrimoAnno").click(function(){
    $anno = ($(this).attr('data-value')); 
    $.getScript("inserisciMateria.js");
  });
  $("#ShowSecondoAnno").click(function(){
    $anno = ($(this).attr('data-value'));
  });
  $("#ShowTerzoAnno").click(function(){
    $anno = ($(this).attr('data-value'));
  });
  $("#ShowQuartoAnno").click(function(){
    $anno = ($(this).attr('data-value'));
  });
  $("#ShowQuintoAnno").click(function(){
    $anno = ($(this).attr('data-value'));
  });

});
```

The main page and the function takes the content from a js file called **inserisciMateria**

```
var card1 = "<div class=\"container\"><div class=\"img-container\"><img src=\"imgs/";
var card2 = ".jpg\"></div><div class=\"content\"><div class=\"head\">"
var card3 = "</div><div class=\"preferiti\"><img src=\"imgs/wishlist.png\" alt=\"Mia Immagine\"></div><div class=\"inner-data\">";
var card4 = "</div><div class=\"anno\">Anno: ";
var card5 = "</div><div class=\"difficolta\">Difficolta\': ";
var card6 = "</div><div class=\"info\"><a href=\"";
var card7 = "\" target=\"_blank\">Per saperne di più</a><i class=\"far fa-heart\"></i></div></div></div></div>";
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.ajax({
    url:'action.php',
    type: 'GET',
    success:function(response) {
     var data = JSON.parse(response);
     var n = data.length;
     var finalCard= "";
     for (var i= 0; i < n; i++) {
         finalCard+=card1+data[i].Nome+card2+data[i].Nome+card3+data[i].Descrizione+card4+data[i].Anno+card5+data[i].Difficolta+card6+data[i].Link+card7;
         
     }
     $(".corpo").append(finalCard);
     }
   });
 });
```

And it takes the data from the database by this file called **action.php**

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","","utenti");
$json=array();

$anno=2;

$sql="SELECT * FROM corsi WHERE anno = $anno";
$stmt=$conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$result=$stmt->get_result();
while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
array_push($json, $row);
}
    echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

But it doesn't work... what's missing?

Comment: Does it update the content onload without even pressing the button? Or does it do nothing?

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: it doesn't do nothing...

Comment: Does the ajax call succeed or even happen? Can you see the request in your dev network tab?

Comment: Please provide more information about response which is got from the ajax call in `inserisciMateria` file

Comment: Are you sure the `inserisciMateria` link is correct and successfully loaded ?

Answer (score 0):

you are appending the content in

```
$(".corpo").append(finalCard);
```

you are selecting the area for content "`.corpo`" by class, JS doesn't know which of the different elements with this class to take and this can bring problems, select the area by ID instead.